# How to run a php file after installing LAMP in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I installed lamp on ubuntu. Apache2 and Mysql are working fine.

The folder apache2 is in /etc and contains:

```
apache2.conf  envvars     magic           mods-enabled  sites-available
conf.d        httpd.conf  mods-available  ports.conf    sites-enabled
```

The httpd.conf file is empty. 
As far as windows is concerned apache had a "www" folder where we used to store our php files. What should I do in this case ?
The tutorials given on the internet could not help! :|
Please help!

Comment: What tutorials you followed? How you installed apache? Is it using package manager like `apt-get` or software center or some other process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent folder in Ubuntu should be `/var/www`, unless you changed it yourself. This directory is (by default) defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`, in the line that begins with the word `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: You'll probably need to change permissions for that folder. `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/`

Comment: 777 is rarely the solution to any problem.

Comment: set permission to 777 is not recommended solution, everyone will be able to access your folder, of course that's related with security reason.

Comment: I have my php files in the folder you specify @MariosZindilis but when I access 'localhost' I think my browser is looking for index.html, not index.php (which is what I have). How do I get the php file to run? Also, I have a child theme i would like to run and that is in a separate folder.

Comment: It seems that since 2012, when this answer was first posted, Ubuntu has changed the location of files for the default website on Apache, and it is now `/var/www/html`. That directory includes a sample `index.html` in a fresh installation.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running  your file just for the localhost then change the chmod to 777 for /var/www/html 
save every php file in html folder which is found in the path mentioned above. The new apache loads the file from the server only if it is present in the HtMl folder. 
i hope it will work.
(Though 777 chmod is not recommended  of course because of the security issues)